# how can we mute the audio when we use AVPlayer for playing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I am playing the audio file by using the below code.

```
    -(IBAction)hearAudioMessage:(id)sender
{
ChatObject * obj = [chatArray objectAtIndex:rowIndexInt];
 NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver.com/files/%@",obj.voiceFileString];
    self.palyer=[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    [self.palyer play];
}
```

Now, i want to mute the audio while playing.

i used the below code but, it did not work me

```
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =
    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];
```

Please suggest any alternative?  or how can we mute the audio when we use AVPlayer for playing

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does “did not work for me” mean? The sound plays anyway? Also, you say that you play an audio file — and then you say you want to mute the audio while playing?

Comment: yeah sound is playing.. i want to mute the audio @zoul

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the below line to mute your audio

[player pause];